# curve_fit impossible if the function calls minimize

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scatter-plot, linspace

Say I have a function **f1**, of an independent variable *x* and a parameter *a*.
The function **f1**, in turn, needs a parameter *m* that can be obtained minimizing a second function **f2**, and this function needs the variable *x* as a parameter.

I have no problem calling **f1**(*x*,*a*) with any value, but if I try to make a fit with `curve_fit` of it, it throws a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. I guess it does it since it assigns not a single *x* value, but the whole array.

There is no way to make `curve_fit` work ?

Toy code, to check the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from random import uniform

def f1(x,a):
    m =  minimize(f2,0.,args=(x)).x[0]
    return (x + a + m)**2
def f2(theta,a):
    return (theta-a)**2

xs = np.linspace(-3.,3.,10)   
ys = [round(f1(x,0.5)-uniform(-1,1),2) for x in xs]
plt.scatter(xs,ys)
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f1, xs, ys, [0.3])
plt.plot(xs,[f1(x,popt[0]) for x in xs])
```

Full traceback:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-5db669cee585> in <module>()
     10 plt.scatter(xs,ys)
     11 plt.plot(xs,[f1(x,0.5) for x in xs])
---> 12 popt,pcov = curve_fit(f1, xs, ys, [0.3])
     13 plt.plot(xs,[f1(x,popt[0]) for x in xs])

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    749         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    750         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 751         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    752         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    381     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    382         args = (args,)
--> 383     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385     if n > m:

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     25 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     26                 output_shape=None):
---> 27     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     28     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     29         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in func_wrapped(params)
    461     if transform is None:
    462         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 463             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    464     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    465         def func_wrapped(params):

<ipython-input-87-5db669cee585> in f1(x, a)
      1 from scipy.optimize import minimize
      2 def f1(x,a):
----> 3     m =  minimize(f2,0.,args=(x)).x[0]
      4     return (x + a + m)**2
      5 def f2(theta,a):

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.pyc in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    595         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    596     elif meth == 'bfgs':
--> 597         return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    598     elif meth == 'newton-cg':
    599         return _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
    961     else:
    962         grad_calls, myfprime = wrap_function(fprime, args)
--> 963     gfk = myfprime(x0)
    964     k = 0
    965     N = len(x0)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    291     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    292         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 293         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    294 
    295     return ncalls, function_wrapper

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in approx_fprime(xk, f, epsilon, *args)
    721 
    722     """
--> 723     return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
    724 
    725 

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.pyc in _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args, f0)
    661         ei[k] = 1.0
    662         d = epsilon * ei
--> 663         grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]
    664         ei[k] = 0.0
    665     return grad

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Would you please add a small amount of data and all import statements? I would like to make sure that I am using the exact same code that you use.

Comment: added all the imports needed, sorry!

Comment: The complete traceback might help too.

Comment: The function passed to minimize should return a single value. For example, it could return the sum of squared error.

Comment: yes, f2 returns simply (theta-a)**2

Comment: @Davis Herring done